# I can't receive a form input array in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

This is the form in the laravel view:

```
<a id="agregarCampo" class="btn btn-info" href="#">Agregar Campo</a>
                <div id="contenedor">
                    <div class="added">
                        <input type="text" name="mitexto[]" id="campo_1" placeholder="Texto 1"/><a href="#" class="eliminar">&times;</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is the jquery file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var MaxInputs       = 8; //Número Maximo de Campos
    var contenedor       = $("#contenedor"); //ID del contenedor
    var AddButton       = $("#agregarCampo"); //ID del Botón Agregar

    //var x = número de campos existentes en el contenedor
    var x = $("#contenedor div").length + 1;
    var FieldCount = x-1; //para el seguimiento de los campos

    $(AddButton).click(function (e) {
        if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
        {
            FieldCount++;
            //agregar campo
            $(contenedor).append('<div><input type="text" name="mitexto[]" id="campo_'+ FieldCount +'" placeholder="Texto '+ FieldCount +'"/><a href="#" class="eliminar">&times;</a></div>');
            x++; //text box increment
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("body").on("click",".eliminar", function(e){ //click en eliminar campo
        if( x > 1 ) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //eliminar el campo
            x--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

This is my controller:

```
$textos = \Input::get('mitexto');
        foreach($textos as $texto) 
        {
            echo $texto.'</br>';
        }
        return 'fin';
```

When i send the form with 3 new fields created dynamically, output:

```
field1
fin
```

Jquery create 3 new fields, but in laravel only recieve the array index 0.

Why does not work?

Comment: First of all, this is not the form. This is just the part of it :) Show us the whole form.

Comment: to get array inputs use dot notation like this Input::get('mitexto.0');   and     Input::all(); will give you all input data